# Parsing decrypted PGP email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pgp, gpgme

I have a problem with decrypted email content that is encrypted with PGP.
When I decrypt the mail using mail-gpg (or any other gem) the result is not a mail object; it'ss just the source of email, something like the structure below.

I tried using the mail gem and also another gem called mail_parser and none of them could parse this source.

Here is an example of the decrypted source:

```
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 0A8387EEB8F331211, created 2019-06-18
      "reza-dev@stg-consulting.test.de"
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 5CA8644C56CC12BD, created 2019-06-18
      "test-dev-test-de@test.de <test-dev-test-de@test.de>"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="3c4321aa4bd8591a78df6a5539b7bbb2"

--3c4321aa4bd8591a78df6a5539b7bbb2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="msg.txt"

Subject: subject is encrypted too

Why body and subject is encrypted =3F

--3c4321aa4bd8591a78df6a5539b7bbb2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="Modern.srt"

77u/MQ0KMDA6MDA6MDMsMjM3IC0tPiAwMDowMDowNSw2MzkNCuKAq9qG2LHYpyDYrdix2YEg2YbZ
hduM2LLZhtuM2J8NCuKAq9in2LIg2K/Ys9iqINmF2YYg2LnYtdio2KfZhtuMINmH2LPYqtuM2J8N


--3c5991aa4bd8591a78df6a5539b7aaa2
```

Comment: The mail gem doesn't seem to have any problem parsing the data you've given: https://repl.it/@jrunning/CyanCulturedBoolean

Comment: Thanks jordan,
But its still look a bit problematic, for example , you cant read subject out of it
Check this out : https://repl.it/repls/JumboUnlinedTheories @JordanRunning

Comment: In your example data the subject line is part of the message body (it appears after the part’s headers and the blank line that indicates the end of the headers) and so won’t be extracted by the mail gem.

Comment: I can extract subject with regex, but how about other data , such as from address , cc , bcc ,to and other details, still can't parse them with mail gem @JordanRunning , is that right ? any other solution you may have?

Comment: The example data you posted doesn’t have any of those headers, so I’m not sure how to help you; sorry.